# CackePHP 3.8 Disable assets loading from tmp/cache

Tags: caching, cakephp, assets

I am using CakePHP version 3.8. After disabling the cache completely, Assets are still loading from tmp/cache folder...I want the assets to be loaded directly

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Without showing your settings, we can't give an answer.

Comment: Neither does CakePHP write assets to the `tmp` folder, nor is the `tmp` folder web accessible by default, so whatever your application is doing there, it's something custom that nobody here has any idea about. As @Salines said, you need to provide more details about how your asset handling works.